# The Great British Arqade Meetup

Tags: discussion, meetup

The other post was getting a bit long and convoluted so let's have another stab at this. This is for the **London meetup**. You don't actually have to be British, but it helps.

Some people have suggested **early August** as a good timeframe, so lets see how that works for people.

## [Fill out your availability here](http://www.doodle.com/ks7c66g7kv4t6i6k)

and we can work out a good date.

Comment: +1 would love to come but I'm from Aus and getting there would be a pain. Also, Obligatory: [Real Life? Never heard of that server](https://p.twimg.com/AwtvZRsCEAE2TFt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Knowing dates in advance will help me arrange time off work and travel, possibly a room for the night (as I'd be coming from Lancaster)

Comment: I'll close the poll well in advance, notify people and pick a date. There should be plenty of time!